# Weird issue with object within class(John Resig simple inheritence)

Tags: javascript, inheritance, canvas

Here is the fiddle

this one works

http://jsfiddle.net/P72UR/

this one doesn't

http://jsfiddle.net/j86TA/1/

Sorry I included so much code just wanted to get the test as close as possible.

Second one is using an object to hold x and y values.  First one is not.

This is probably a function binding issue but I'm not entirely sure.

I have this code:

```
 (function createClouds() {

        var Cloud = Class.extend({

            size: 0,
            alpha: 0,

            x: 0,
            y: 0,

            pos: {
                x: 0,
                y: 0
            },

            init: function (x, y, size, alpha) {

                this.x = x;
                this.y = y;
                this.size = size;
                this.alpha = alpha;

console.log(this.x) // this prints a random number.  all good

            },

            update: function (time) {

            },

            draw: function (ctx) {

                ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(255, 255, 255, ' + this.alpha + ')';
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.size, this.size);
                ctx.closePath();
                ctx.fill();
            }
        });

        sg.Cloud = Cloud;

    })();
```

Then I'm basically creating this object with random points on the canvas.

```
 for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {

        var x = sg.util.getRandomInt(0, sg.currentGame.width);
        var y = sg.util.getRandomInt(0, sg.currentGame.height - 260);
        var size = sg.util.getRandomInt(20, 200);
        var alpha = sg.util.getRandomNumber(.1, .6);

        sg.createEntity(new sg.Cloud(x, y, size, alpha));
    }
```

The sg.createEntity adds this entity to an array;

I then call a method.

```
 for (var i = 0; i < sg.entities.length; i++) {
                sg.entities[i].draw(this.context);
            }
```

That draws all the entities.

The above works fine.  I get random points.

If I change this.

```
 (function createClouds() {

        var Cloud = Class.extend({

            size: 0,
            alpha: 0,

            x: 0,
            y: 0,

            pos: {
                x: 0,
                y: 0
            },

            init: function (x, y, size, alpha) {

                this.pos.x = x;
                this.pos.y = y;
                this.size = size;
                this.alpha = alpha;

console.log(this.pos.x) //this prints a random number;
console.log(this.pos) //inspecting this object shows same points.

            },

            update: function (time) {

            },

            draw: function (ctx) {

                ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(255, 255, 255, ' + this.alpha + ')';
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.fillRect(this.pos.x, this.pos.y, this.size, this.size);
                ctx.closePath();
                ctx.fill();
            }
        });

        sg.Cloud = Cloud;

    })();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `.extend()` makes a shallow copy of the base object, but `.pos` is an object and so copying it will cause more references to itself instead of new instances.

The following is a small example of what happens:

```
var a = { x: 0 }, b = a;

b.x = 4;

console.log(a.x); // prints 4
```

I'm not sure how to solve it though, because it doesn't seem like it was meant to handle object properties properly.